# On the proof of diagonalization of real symmetric matrix

Tags: reference-request, symmetric-matrices

It is well-known that every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix. However, it is hard to understand it intuitively(geometrically). I wonder whether we can show it without invoking mathematical induction (in the size of square matrices).

Comment: I do not think that the usual way to prove this is induction over the matrix size (how would an induction proof look like here?) , neither do I think that there is a geometric/intuitive proof.

Comment: Induction is pretty natural: to prove that a real symmetric matrix $A$ is diagonalizable you need to show that it has an eigenvector. There's a geometric argument for that: pick $v$ of length $1$ such that $\|Av\|$ is largest. A variational argument proves that $Av$ must be parallel to $v$. Now since $A$ preserves the subspace $W = \mathop{\rm span}\{v\}$ and $A$ is symmetric, it must also preserve the subspace $W^\perp$, which is of smaller dimension.

Comment: One usual way is to establish (upper) triangulation of every (not necessarily symmetric) matrix by a unitary matrix and then we restrict our interest to the symmetric case. But induction is usually used in the proof of triangulation.

Comment: For the geometric meaning, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem Though the proof is algebraic.